# How to access base part of a derived class object using . operator

Tags: c++

I did overloading of '+' operator using friend functions for base and derived classes as below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        base(int a) : x(a)
        {
        }

        void printx()
        {
            cout << "x : " << x << endl;
        }

        friend void operator+(int data, base &obj);
};

void operator+(int data, base &obj)
{
    cout << "in friend base" << endl;
    obj.x = data + obj.x;
}

class derived : public base
{
    private:
        int y;

    public:
        derived(int a, int b) : base(a), y(b)
        {
        }

        void printy()
        {
            cout << "y : " << y << endl;
        }

        friend void operator+(int data, derived &obj);
};

void operator+(int data, derived &obj)
{
    cout << "in friend derived" << endl;

   operator+(data, obj.base);
    obj.y = data + obj.y;
    cout << "y in friend : " << obj.y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    derived c(2, 3);

    4 + c;

    c.printx();
    c.printy();
}
```

But this is giving compilation error as below

```
inoverload+.cpp: In function ‘void operator+(int, derived&)’:
inoverload+.cpp:51:25: error: invalid use of ‘base::base’
     operator+(data, obj.base);
```

While the below program is getting successfully compiled.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
        int x;

        base(int a) : x(a)
        {
        }
};

class d1 : public base
{
    public:
        d1(int a) : base(a)
        {
        }
};

class d2 : public base
{
    public:
        d2(int a) : base(a)
        {
        }
};

class derived : public d1, public d2
{
    public:
        derived(int a) : d1(a), d2(a)
        {
        }
};

int main()
{
    derived obj(2);

    cout << obj.d1::x << endl;
}
```

Can any one please explain why I was not able to access the base part using derived class object in first program where as I am able to do the same in the same program.

Note : I already tried with cast and it worked. But my question is if it is not correct to access base using obj.base how this is correct in second program obj.d1::x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot operator is for *member access*. But there is not a `base` member in `derived`, so `obj.base` is ill-formed. To obtain a base class reference explicitly from a derived object, you need to cast:

```
operator+(data, static_cast<base&>(obj));
```

In the second program `obj.d1::x` does not access the *member* `d1`. It accesses the member `x`. However, to resolve ambiguity, C++ allows to use the scope resolution operator to disambiguate in which unique base class sub-object this member is found.

Comment: @Knoep - Oh, well. Tunnel vision

Comment: I forgot to mention. I already tried with cast and it worked. My question is if obj.base is ill formed why not obj.d1 in second program?

Comment: Just because they _shouldn't_ doesn't mean they don't :)

Comment: @kadina - Hope I addressed that now

Comment: @StoryTeller - I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The line `operator+(data, obj.base);` implies that `obj` has a member named `base`, which is not true. The base portion of a derived object is not represented as a member.

To coerce overloading to consider your object as if it was it's base type, you can case it to a reference of it's base class. The compiler must then treat it as if it's type was strictly the base type for that function call. Try the following :

```
void operator+(int data, derived &obj)
{
    cout << "in friend derived" << endl;

    operator+(data, static_cast<base&>(obj)); // Cast happens here
    obj.y = data + obj.y;
    cout << "y in friend : " << obj.y << endl;
}
```